# How to include selenium with pyinstall

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I've got my script running fine using selenium web driver

In order to avoid the issue where users have mismatch versions of chrome and chromium extensions I use web driver to download the last versions at runtime.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

So I don't have to include any chromium binaries in the spec file as it's downloaded at runtime (right?)
Everything is working, but when I try to build an unix executable file
with pyinstaller, I don't know what binaries should I include in the spec file, (I mean the path to selenium) and as a result it cannot find the selenium module and outputs me the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

(only with the 'standalone' build with pyinstall, the scripts don't sent me this error)

Answer (score 0):

So on Mac the full package is located here:
Library/python/x.x/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/

and I had to include it in the spec file within
the binaries with the project :
binaries=[('/Users/myusername/ProjectDir', '/Users/myusername/Library/Python/x.x/lib/python/site-packages/selenium')],